# Switch in constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, c++17

Found the following statement in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions):

> C++11 introduced the concept of a constexpr-declared function; a
>   function which could be executed at compile time. Their return values
>   could be consumed by operations that require constant expressions,
>   such as an integer template argument. However, C++11 constexpr
>   functions could only contain a single expression that is returned (as
>   well as static_asserts and a small number of other declarations).
>
> C++14 relaxes these restrictions. Constexpr-declared functions may now
>   contain the following: The conditional
>
> - ...
> - branching statements `if` and `switch`

So, Is it actually possible to have a switch in a constexpr function in c++14/c++17? And, if possible, what syntax is for that?
For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
enum class Terrain : std::uintmax_t {
    ROAD,
    SOIL,
    GRASS,
    MUD,
    SNOW,
};

constexpr float
getStepPrice(Terrain const& terrain)
{
    switch constexpr (terrain)
    {
        case Terrain::ROAD: return 1.0f;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling that?

Comment: I mean, this works: http://ideone.com/pjMrvr

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Uh, oh. Turned out it just was a bug in my older g++ (4.9.2). But it works in clang 3.5

Comment: I learned nothing from this whole page.

Comment: Actual answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379817/1599699

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> So, Is it actually possible to have a switch in a constexpr function in c++14/c++17?

Yes.

> And, if possible, what syntax is for that?

There is absolutely nothing special about the syntax, it's just a normal `switch`. Like this:

```
constexpr int fun (int i) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0: return 7;
        default: return 5;
    }
}

int main () {
    int arr[fun(3)];
}
```

Comment: Not that a static switch (just like a static loop) wouldn't be nice to have. A library-solution has some significant drawbacks.

Answer (score 30):

Not exactly.  In the case of `if constexpr`, you can rest assured that the resulting code has no branching.  Moreover, discarded statements need not compile.  Those are the guarantees I think you would expect from a true `switch constexpr`.

```
class Dog;
class Snake;

#define USE_IF

template<typename Pet>
constexpr void foo(Pet pet) {
#ifdef USE_IF
    // This works
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Pet, Dog>)   pet.bark();
    else                                     pet.slither();
#else
    // This doesn't
    switch (std::is_same_v<Pet, Dog>) {
        case true:  pet.bark();    break;  // <== Error if Snake
        case false: pet.slither(); break;  // <== Error if Dog
    }
#else
}
```

BTW, I'm being a little nit-picky vis-a-vis Baum's accepted answer, which is fine, for practical puposes.  I suspect you'd find good compilers will elide logically impossible bits from a switch-case statement with constexpr functions, as well as even non-constexpr inlined functions.