# If there's an if-constexpr, how come there's no switch-constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, if-constexpr

In C++17, [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) was introduced; however, there doesn't seem to be a `switch constexpr` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)). Why is that? That is, if a compiler supports `if constexpr`, is it not also trivial for it to support `switch constexpr` (at worst as an if-then-else-if-etc. chain, or multiple if's with some flags to control fallthrough)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`if constexpr`](https://wg21.link/P0128R1) was ultimately derived from a [more sane form](https://wg21.link/N4461) of the [`static if` concept](https://wg21.link/N3329). Because of that derivation, applying the same idea to `switch` does not appear to have been considered by the standards committee. So this is likely the primary reason: nobody added it to the paper since it was a restricted form of a syntax where `switch` wouldn't have made sense.

That being said, `switch` has a lot of baggage in it. The most notable bit being the automatic fallthrough behavior. That makes defining its behavior a bit problematic.

See, one of the powers of `if constexpr` is to make the side not taken at compile time be discarded under certain conditions. This is an important part of the syntax. So a hypothetical `switch constexpr` would be expected to have similar powers.

That's a lot harder to do with fallthrough, since the `case` blocks are not as fundamentally distinct as the two blocks of an `if` statement. Especially if you have *conditional* fallthrough. Now, you could make `switch constexpr` not have automatic fallthrough (or fallthrough at all), so that the different sections are distinct. But then you've subtly changed how the syntax works; a non-`constexpr` form of `switch` behaves differently from the `constexpr` form. That's not good.

Yes, you could make it a compile error to not put `break;` statements between the labels.

Note that the two main pattern-matching proposals, [P1308](https://wg21.link/P1308) and [P1260](https://wg21.link/P1260), specifically *avoid* using `switch`, instead inventing a new keyword. They both have `constexpr` aspects to them, but they make it abundantly clear that they are not `switch/case`.

Comment: While both proposals are interesting, P1308 introduces syntax that looks very little like current C++. P2160 is quite a fascinating paper.

Comment: @JonHarper: "*P1308 introduces syntax that looks very little like current C++.*" You know, normally I would have responded with "you say that as if it's a bad thing ;)". But after looking at that proposal, it's kinda scary in there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not authoritative, but if you look at the [selection statements](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select) `if` has a clear separation between true and false statements, `switch` doesn't.

I presume it would be relatively harder to discard unused parts of switch from evaluation, especially since they can fall-through.

Reimplementing `switch` as `if-else-if` is not so straight forward if you want to maintain all the (exotic) capabilities of it.

Comment: I'm sure there is a simple way to transform any `switch` into a tree of `if` branches, even considering fallthrough.

Comment: See Duff's device. `switch` is a lot less structured than most people think.

Comment: @T.C. I am not sure who what were you commenting on, my answer or the 1st comment, but that is exactly my point. Because of such lack of the structure it would be pretty hard to reimplement it. It's way easier to base discarding rules on whole statement - using existing syntax, than coming up with custom rules for something amorphous.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following example from [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972822/3854570) (about optimized `if` branches).

```
struct Cat { void meow() { } };
struct Dog { void bark() { } };

template <typename T>
void pet(T x)
{
    if(std::is_same<T, Cat>{}){ x.meow(); }
    else if(std::is_same<T, Dog>{}){ x.bark(); }
}

pet(Cat{});
pet(Dog{});
```

You cannot replicate this with a switch because you would need the case values to actually be types; something like the following, which is impossible for obvious reasons.

```
template <typename T>
void pet(T x)
{
    switch (T) {
    case Cat:
        x.meow();
        break;
    case Dog:
        x.meow();
        break;
    }
}
```

This example is kind of the reason for `if constexpr`: comparing types or other things that aren't simply a set of values. So a `switch constexpr` does not make much sense to me. If anything, it would need another syntax (kind of like my example), and I'm not sure that it would be beneficial. It certainly isn't necessary.